# VBA Userform programming script

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I'm trying to make this code open specific sheets in excel using the exact sheet name as an input to get to it. If the sheet name is not there or spelled incorrectly it should display the "Please use another Sheet name" message. I have this so far, but the "Case Else" part is giving me issues. I appreciate your help.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Sheetname As String
whichSheet = InputBox("In which sheet do you wish to enter data? Specify sheet number as Toner, Copy Paper,etc.", "Input")
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
    Select Case ws.CodeName
        Case "Toner", "Copy Paper", "Mail Package", "Alteration", "Gloves", "Special Requests"
            Worksheets(whichSheet).Activate ws.Name
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Please use another Sheet name"
            Exit Sub
    End Select
Next ws

Worksheets(whichSheet).Activate
Dim lastrow
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

lastrow = lastrow + 1
Cells(lastrow, 1) = TextBox1
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A2:A" & lastrow), Cells(lastrow, 1)) > 1 Then
MsgBox "Submitting Entry"
Cells(lastrow, 1) = ""

Cells(lastrow, 1) = TextBox1.Text
Cells(lastrow, 2) = TextBox2.Text
Cells(lastrow, 3) = TextBox3.Value
Cells(lastrow, 4) = TextBox4.Text
Cells(lastrow, 5) = TextBox5.Text
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: 1) Why aren't you using the code I supplied in your earlier question? 2) What does "giving me issues" mean exactly? I imagine the code will always go to that statement as you are basing your Select Case on the sheet code name which is different to the name shown on the sheet tab.

Comment: I did use it and it worked for the first part of the code but the info I entered in the userform wouldn't populate the sheet after I submitted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, which builds on the previous code, and avoids activating the sheet. Doing this is not the end of the world but is not necessary.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim whichSheet As String, lastrow As Long

whichSheet = InputBox("In which sheet do you wish to enter data? Type in sheet name as Toner, Copy Paper, Alteration, Mail Package, Gloves, and Special Requests.", "Input")

Select Case whichSheet
    Case "Toner", "Copy Paper", "Mail Package", "Alteration", "Gloves", "Special Requests"
        With Worksheets(whichSheet)
            lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Cells(lastrow, 1) = TextBox1
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("A2:A" & lastrow), .Cells(lastrow, 1)) > 1 Then
                MsgBox "Submitting Entry"
                .Cells(lastrow, 1) = ""
                .Cells(lastrow, 1) = TextBox1.Text
                .Cells(lastrow, 2) = TextBox2.Text
                .Cells(lastrow, 3) = TextBox3.Value
                .Cells(lastrow, 4) = TextBox4.Text
                .Cells(lastrow, 5) = TextBox5.Text
            End If
        End With
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Please use another Sheet name"
        Exit Sub
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I see what you mean it doesn't activate the sheet. But I think I will just create a button for each sheet that will activate the userform. I like this code better though thanks.